# Show External Window When Mirroring (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm implementing a feature in my iPhone/iPad app where when the iPhone is connected to an external display, the iPhone acts as a controller and the external display shows a non-interactive view. I'm using SwiftUI.

My application is actually quite a similar concept to the one in Apple's documentation. The iPhone/iPad will always be used as a controller while the external display will always show the content, in Apple's case, a game. For this reason, when mirroring the game to QuickTime or StreamLabs, *the actual game needs to be mirrored, not the controller*. Here's the example I'm talking about in Apple's documentation so that you can visualize it.

[image: Source: Apple]

### Current Implementation

Here's how I've implemented it in the `SceneDelegate`, following Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/presenting_content_on_a_connected_display).

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    if session.role == .windowApplication {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    if session.role == .windowExternalDisplayNonInteractive {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ExternalView())
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Where, of course, `ContentView` should be displayed on the iPhone and `ExternalView` is displayed on the external display or QuickTime. And here's my `info.plist` entry if that's relevant to you.

[image: The info.plist containing the entries for the windows]

### Outcome and the Problem

Ok, so this works fine for most cases, like when screen mirroring from my iPhone to a TV using AirPlay. Both views are displayed correctly. The problem I'm having, though, is that in certain cases, like trying to do a movie recording in QuickTime with the iPhone as the source or adding the iPhone as a video capture device in StreamLabs, the iPhone's screen (with the `ContentView`) is mirrored, instead of showing the `ExternalView`. The `ExternalView` *needs* to be shown when using these apps.

When looking at `UIApplication.shared.openSessions`, only one session is listed as described bellow

```
▿ 1 member
  - <UISceneSession: 0x283594ac0; role: UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication; persistentIdentifier: ED82F2B9-17EC-435F-8E20-439CECCA92F6> {
    scene = <UIWindowScene: 0x117d051e0>;
    configuration = <UISceneConfiguration: 0x283595cc0; name: ContentView; role: UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication> {
        sceneClass = 0x0;
        delegateClass = SwiftUI.AppSceneDelegate;
        storyboard = 0x0;
    };
} #0
    - super: NSObject
```

Is there a way to "create" a new session for screen mirroring? I'm beginning to worry that this is not possible with apps like QuickTime and StreamLabs and not something I can fix on my end.

Anyway, if you have any solutions to this issue I would very much appreciate any feedback at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this is not possible yet as far as I can tell. I have looked into this quite a bit and hope someone proves me wrong.

No screen mirroring or recording app supports recording the second display.

You can either mirror to your Mac or PC (with [Reflector](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector) and record from there or go the Hardware route by using a capture card like the Elgato Game Capture HD60s with either a [Lightning](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD826AM/A/lightning-digital-av-adapter) or [USB-C](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) adapter and then stream the gameplay form your PC.

If you hope to make your game streamable this won't help you though.